# How to keep my App tracking time , to execute a particular action on a specific time

Tags: android

Muslims prayer times are 5 time a day , so i want my app to always check time , and when the current time matches with one from the 5 time, the App trigger an Action like play a media file , or send A notification to the userю

Answer (score 0):

Use AlarmManager

```
 AlarmManager mAlarmManger = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

 //Create pending intent & register it to your alarm notifier class
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver_maandag_1e.class);
 intent.putExtra("uur", "1e"); // if you want
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

 //set timer you want alarm to work (here I have set it to 9.00)
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
 calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
 calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

//set that timer as a RTC Wakeup to alarm manager object
mAlarmManger.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Thanks to zipo13 for the correction. As GoogleDeveloper say

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

Comment: Do not use mAlarmManger.set as if the phone is asleep the alarm might not pop up. Use mAlarmManger.setExact instead